# import db with mysql ,missing one column

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to import some data into mysql using phpmyadmin .Data file is in text format , ';'separated and each row also terminated by ; and new line.
nothing is in double quotes.

Mysql table has one extra column of primary key auto-incremented which is not in txt file ofourse.
So import is missing the first column ( url -contains big url itself) always and all columns are shift to left.
primary key -is filled up correct.

1.What do i do here?I am not much into dbs .Please suggest.
2.Also what is better to do larger import.i get error in that case too. i tried on cmd-line but access denied.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with the mysqlimport tool, which I resolved by explicitly specifying the columns:

```
./mysqlimport --local --fields-terminated-by=',' --ignore-lines=1 
--columns=establishment,town,county,chef michelin michelin_stars.csv
```

If the columns in your input file do not exactly match the columns in your table, you need to specify them. I assume the phpadmin tool allows this too somewhere.